# Debugging angular 12 application

Tags: angular, safari, capacitor, tsconfig

my tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "jszip": ["node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

local variables got shorten names with random letters:
[shorten name illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUuXq.png)

[image]

How i can change this compilation behaving and get the full names (as in my code) ?

Comment: If you are creating a production build, the shortening of variable names is expected.  It is unusual for that to happen when running a dev build.  Are you running a default project created with the Angular CLI?

Comment: yes using the default settings